# Получение значений переменной

Tags: jquery, javascript

есть инпут вводим в него значение и это значение отпровляется обработчику, далее приходит ответ в формате xml, далее перебираем xml и создаем переменные window.ekza и window.summa затем мы должны получить значение этих переменных

< input class="vedomost_apelliasia" predmet_id="10" shifr="5" type="text"  / >

```
$(".vedomost_apelliasia").live("keydown",function(e){
  if (e.which == 13){
      predmet_id=$(this).attr("predmet_id");
      shifr=$(this).attr("shifr");
      otvet = $(this).val();
      if((predmet_id!='')&&(shifr!='')&&(otvet!='')){
        $.post("http://localhost/admin/vedomost_apelliasia_result.php", {predmet_id:predmet_id,shifr:shifr,otvet:otvet},
        function (xml){
              $(xml).find('stud_xml').each(function(){
                  window.ekza = $(this).find('ekza').text();
                  window.summa = $(this).find('summa').text();
              });
      });
    }
    alert(window.summa);//тута проблемма summa выводится когда захожу сюда в первый раз как получить значение переменной summa в этом случае
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Как сообщил [[[[@lampa](/users/5030/lampa)](/users/5030/lampa)](/users/5030/lampa)](/users/5030/lampa) alert() выполняется в потоке и не ждет результатов работы ajax запроса. решений может быть несколько. Или ставить интервал на проверку появилось ли значение (см. пример от [[[[@lampa](/users/5030/lampa)](/users/5030/lampa)](/users/5030/lampa)](/users/5030/lampa)) или в callback запускать функцию которая и будет делать дальше все манипуляции. Во-втором случае не надо напрягать браузер постоянными проверками. Пришел ответ от сервера- выполнились данные. Пример:

в начале до вызова аякса сохраняем объект по которому клацнули

```
var curObj = this;

function (xml){
  $(xml).find('stud_xml').each(function(){
     window.ekza = $(this).find('ekza').text();
     window.summa = $(this).find('summa').text();
     someCoolFunction(curObj);
   });
 });

function someCoolFunction(obj){
  $(obj).parent().text(window.summa);
};
```

**UPD:** поправил согласно комментария.

Comment: Согласен, ваш пример лучше.

Answer (score -1):

У вас `alert()` выполняется раньше, чем происходит загрузка файла через `$.post`.

Как решение проблемы:

```
timer = setInterval(function() {
    if(window.summa != undefined) {
        alert(window.summa);
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Прошу прошение у меня вместо алерта должна стоят этот код алерт я поставил для проверки
$(this).parent().text(window.summa);